# Intersecting plane and Lp ball

Tags: visualization

It's easy to visualize intersection of Lp-ball and a plane by using `RegionFunction`.

```
 ContourPlot3D[{Norm[{x, y, z}, 1.5] == 1}, {x, -b, b}, {y, -b, 
   b}, {z, -b, b}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]} . {x, y} > 0], 
  PlotPoints -> 2, Mesh -> None], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

However, this is slow, and doesn't generalize to more dimensions.
What's the most elegant way to visualize this cross-section using a 2D plot instead of 3D?

IE, something like `RegionPlot[{Norm[{x, y}, 1.5] < 1}, {x, -b, b}, {y, -b, b}]`, but for intersection of Lp-ball in d-dimensions with a plane passing through origin.

[image]

Comment: Your term " Lp-ball " is not standard (see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lp_spaces)  and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Lp+space&title=Special:Search&ns0=1)).

Comment: Well, there's L2 ball, L1 ball

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `ClipPlanes` is faster.

```
b = 1;
g = ContourPlot3D[{Norm[{x, y, z}, 1.5] == 1}, {x, -b, b}, {y, -b, 
    b}, {z, -b, b}];
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[g[[1]], ClipPlanes -> {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0, 0}], {t, 0, 
  2 Pi}]
```

[image]

- Here we also try to view the intersection of the ball respect to $L^{p}$ norm and the plane

```
Clear[b];
b = 1;
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} . {x, y} == 0, {x, -b, 
   b}, {y, -b, b}, {z, -b, b}, PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, Norm[{x, y, z}, 1.5] - 1], 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Red, None}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None], {{θ, π/2}, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

- Clip the $L^{p}$ norm ball by any plane.

```
Clear[f, b, g, pt, normal, clip];
f[x_, y_, z_] = Norm[{x, y, z}, 1.5] - 1;
b = 1;
g = ContourPlot3D[{f[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, -b, b}, {y, -b, b}, {z, -b, 
    b}];
pt = {.1, .2, .3};
normal = {-3, -5, 8};
clip = ContourPlot3D[
   normal . ({x, y, z} - pt) == 0, {x, -b, b}, {y, -b, b}, {z, -b, b},
    MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, f[x, y, z]], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshShading -> {Red, None}, BoundaryStyle -> None];
Graphics3D[{{ClipPlanes -> Flatten[{-normal, normal . pt}], 
   g[[1]]}, {clip[[1]]}, {Arrow[Tube@{pt, pt + Normalize@normal}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, MeshFunctions seems to be the main trick here. This + `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"` essentially gets me the animation I wanted.